# Debug Visualforce Button

Tags: visualforce, rerender

I have a visualforce page which is a fancy product selector for Opportunities. We show them a list of products in a table they click a button called "Add" it becomes a selected product where the screen refreshes and displays the product in a new section where they can put in the price and the dates.

For some reason for two of these products when you click the "Add" button nothing happens. You can click other "Add" buttons in the other rows of the table and it works fine the page rerenders and life goes on.

How can I debug the button when it doesn't change anything? I tried debug logs but there is no change to trigger the debug log to start. I tried using developer tools in chrome. I can see in the Network tab when the button click works it makes a call to the server and updates. But for these two products nothing...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are saying that for other products the button works but for 2 specific buttons there is no response. Can you please check the records for those two like active/inactive and any other special condition which may not let you select them.

Comment: I figured it out. The two products had an apostrophe ' in them. So my assumption is that the code passes the name as a string to the controller and does a query to get the id. In there the apostrophe breaks the string and doesn't return a value so it stops the whole process. Removing the ' resolved the issue and those two can be added again.

Comment: @DanWooding That should probably be fixed, though... what happens when you have two products with the same name?

Comment: @sfdcfox yeah I need to fix that somehow. The product selector page actually searches for this thing they call product bundles where products that are named the same are grouped together. So you search for the bundle and then in a section you choose details that give you the proper product like accounting unit, or family ect.